# Prove $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^{n}$ are independent iff $F_{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}F_{X_k}(x_k)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^{n}$ be RVs
> Prove $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^{n}$ are independent iff for every $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ :$F_{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}F_{X_k}(x_k)$

I've managed to prove the first part where $X_k$ are independent.
Any help for the second will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the set of intervals of the form $(-\infty, x]$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathcal{B}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the real line. Fix $I_2,...,I_n\in\mathcal{I}$. Then the class
$$\mathcal{G}_1=\left\{B_1\in\mathcal{B} : \mathbb{P}(X_1\in B_1, X_2\in I_2, ..., X_n\in I_n)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\in B_1)\mathbb{P}(X_2\in I_2)\cdots \mathbb{P}(X_n \in I_n) \right\}$$
is a monotone class. Moreover, $\mathcal{I}\subset\mathcal{G}_1$ is stable under finite intersections so the monotone class lemma ensures that $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{I})=\sigma(\mathcal{I})\subset\mathcal{G}_1$. Since $\sigma(\mathcal{I})=\mathcal{B}$, we have shown that for all $B_1\in \mathcal{B}$ and $I_2,...,I_n\in\mathcal{I}$
$$\mathbb{P}(X_1\in B_1, X_2\in I_2,..., X_n\in I_n)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\in B_1)\mathbb{P}(X_2\in I_2)\cdots\mathbb{P}(X_n\in I_n)$$
Proceeding by induction with the same reasoning, we can replace $I_2,...,I_n\in\mathcal{I}$ by $B_2,...,B_n\in\mathcal{B}$ one by one. Once we are done, we can simply notice that we have arrived to the definition of independence.

Comment: The CDF use is at $\mathcal{G}_1$ right?

Comment: You use the property on CDFs to have $\mathcal{I}\subset\mathcal{G}_1$